# how to get maven metadata?

Tags: java, maven, metadata

I want to create an executive summary of all dependencies defined in my pom.xml file, in this summary I must include the type of licensing that each one of my dependencies.

there any way to get this information automatically? perhaps some maven plugin? or something that allows me to get this metadata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing:

```
mvn project-info-reports:dependencies
```

will generate a nice report in `target/site/dependencies.html`